# Reloading dynamically generated pdf document hangs/stalls in Apache with Phusion passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a situation where I'm dynamically generating a pdf document using Ruby on Rails [send_data call] (http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionController/Streaming/send_data).(Rails 2.3.18 ... its a legacy app),

The pdf is always generated fine the first time, but on reload, or making subsequent calls to the same endpoint (doesn't matter what the parameters are in the url) the request just stalls forever. Its the same from the browser, using curl from the commandline ... doesn't matter where or what browser is used.

If I kill the request (by x'ing out of it in the browser, for example, and retrying it) the call succeeds

In tracing the output using logs, I found out that the hung request never gets to the Rails server (Phusion passenger instance), because there are no Rails logs produced for the hung call. They also don't show up in Apache Access Logs since apparently the request never succeeds.

Sometimes in the log, I'll see

```
[ 2015-12-30 16:16:14.0423 14334/7fbb1a32d700 apache2/Hooks.cpp:718 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot connect to the helper agent at /tmp/passenger.1.0.11825/generation-5/request

Backtrace:
 in 'Passenger::FileDescriptor Hooks::connectToHelperAgent()' (Hooks.cpp:283)
 in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:532)
```

Any ideas?